# Animating Color with jQuery Step Function and CSS rgb()

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to do a simple width and background color animation with jQuery (similar to apple.com's search box).

Basically, you focus a form field, and its parent changes background color and gets wider, then, on blur, the parent's width and background color change back.

I don't want to load the jQuery Color plugin for such a simple thing, so I found a work around. The problem is, the background color animates perfectly on focus, but on blur nothing changes. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's my code: (the starting background-color is `rgb(243, 243, 243)` if you were wondering where that number comes from)

```
$('#s').focus(function() {
    $('#header-search-form').animate(
        {'width': '175px'}, { 
        duration  : 150,
        easing    : 'swing',
        step      : function( now, fx ) {
            var completion = ( now - fx.start ) / ( fx.end - fx.start );
            $('#header-search-form').css( 'backgroundColor', 'rgb(' + 243+(255-243)*completion + ',' + 243+(255-243)*completion + ',' + 243+(255-243)*completion + ')' );
        }           
    });
});
$('#s').blur(function() {
    $('#header-search-form').animate(
        {'width': '125px'}, {
        duration  : 150,
        easing    : 'swing',
        step      : function( now, fx ) {
            var completion = ( now - fx.start ) / ( fx.end - fx.start );                    
            $('#header-search-form').css( 'backgroundColor', 'rgb(' + 255-(255-243)*completion + ',' + 255-(255-243)*completion + ',' + 255-(255-243)*completion + ')' );               
        }                   
    });
});
```

Comment: In case anyone is interested, I applied what I learned here to create a simple jQuery plugin for animating colors. You can see it here: https://gist.github.com/dominic-p/4569265

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These numbers are values of Red Green and Blue colors rgb(red, green, blue) this range is between 0 to 255
so `rgb(255,255,255)` is white and `rgb(0,0,0)` is black.

```
        $('#s').focus(function() {
        $('#header-search-form').animate(
    { 'width': '175px' }, {
        duration: 150,
        easing: 'swing',
        step: function(now, fx) {
            var completion = (now - fx.start) / (fx.end - fx.start);
            $('#header-search-form').css('backgroundColor', 'rgb(' + (243 + (255 - 243) * completion) + ',' + (243 + (255 - 243) * completion) + ',' + (243 + (255 - 243) * completion) + ')');
        }
    });
    });
    $('#s').blur(function() {
        $('#header-search-form').animate(
    { 'width': '125px' }, {
        duration: 150,
        easing: 'swing',
        step: function(now, fx) {
            var completion = (now - fx.start) / (fx.end - fx.start);
            $('#header-search-form').css('backgroundColor', 'rgb(' + (255 - (255 - 243) * completion) + ',' + (255 - (255 - 243) * completion) + ',' + (255 - (255 - 243) * completion) + ')');
        }
    });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. Yes, I'm aware of how rgb color declaration works in CSS. My problem is that the blur step function (second one shown) is not animating the colors for some reason.

Comment: try this code for focus `.css('backgroundColor', 'rgb(' + ((243 + (255 - 243) * completion)) + ',' + ((243 + (255 - 243) * completion)) + ',' + (243 + (255 - 243) * completion) + ')');` and this for blur `.css('backgroundColor', 'rgb(' + (255 - (255 - 243) * parseInt(completion)) + ',' + (255 - (255 - 243) * parseInt(completion)) + ',' + (255 - (255 - 243) * parseInt(completion)) + ')');`

Comment: You need parentheses to calculate numbers like `(255 - (255 - 243) * completion)`

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I didn't realize parenthesis were needed. It's working as expected now.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is actually create a variable that holds valid numbers for colors, then it will work.

See this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/2X6QL/

It will show you the numbers returned in your step function, and if they look like rgb numbers between 0 and 255 to you, then your golden, to me the numbers does not look like they will change colors any time soon, and the color animation does not work for me, it turns white because the numbers are off.

I'm not sure how to exactly calculate the numbers for you, as I have no idea what colors your are tryning to match, but I see you are close to some numbers in your calculations, maybe a math.round or parseInt will solve it, I'll have another look and see if rounding the numbers will work?

And it did, here is a working Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/2X6QL/3/

The code:

```
var completion, color;
$('#s').focus(function() {
    $('#header-search-form').animate({
        width: 175
      }, { 
        duration  : 1500,
        easing    : 'swing',
        step      : function(now, fx) {
            completion = ( now - fx.start ) / ( fx.end - fx.start );
            color = Math.round(243+(255-243)*completion) +', '+ Math.round(243+(255-243)*completion) +', '+ Math.round(243+(255-243)*completion);
            $('#header-search-form').css( 'backgroundColor', 'rgb('+color+')' );
        }           
    });
}).blur(function() {
    $('#header-search-form').animate({
        width: 125
       }, {
        duration  : 1500,
        easing    : 'swing',
        step      : function(now, fx) {
            completion = ( now - fx.start ) / ( fx.end - fx.start );                    
            color = Math.round(255-(255-243)*completion) + ', ' + Math.round(255-(255-243)*completion) + ', ' + Math.round(255-(255-243)*completion);
            $('#header-search-form').css( 'backgroundColor', 'rgb('+color+')' );
        }                   
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the helpful solution. This looks like it will work great. I accepted the other solution because it doesn't require an additional variable which I prefer. But, I'm up-voting this as well. Thanks again.

Comment: Thank you, be aware that the other solution still does not set the rgb values in integers, but in numbers with lots of decimals, that are hopefully converted to whole numbers by your browser, you should round the numbers before applying them.

Comment: Ok, thanks for pointing that out. I'll throw in some `Math.round`s just to be safe.